# How to add ssl certificates on mac iOS simulator

Tags: ios, macos, selenium, https, appium

I am running my test cases on mac iOS simulator safari browser using appium . I am getting error message " The identity of 'www.sitename.com' cannot be verified by safari. Review the certificate details to continue " We have **Root.cer** for site. How to add this certificate to mac iOS simulator.

Comment: Try sending the file as an email attachment and then open the recipient's email account in the simulator's browser. Download the file and try to open it. It should automatically add the certificate. I have not tested it though.

Comment: Prerak Sola I have added certificates as per your suggestion but whenever  reset simulator ,I am getting same error message. I am executing test cases continuously.After completion of one test case simulator is closed and again simulator is launched for next test case execution . For each and every test case execution I have to click on continue button manually.